# Problem when i using https call api to http in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have this error:
`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myWebsite' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://myApi'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`
My API just using HTTP and cant not change it to HTTPS, somebody helps me this issue

Answer (score 2):

Add the following in the `<head>` tag of your website:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

Comment: I tried but not working